# Why .click is not working.

Tags: jquery, html

I'm very new to Jquery and I have an html element like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="supportButton" id="whitelist.onCancelUploadButton" onclick="whitelist.onCancelUpload();">
```

For this input I can trigger the `click` as :

```
$('#whitelist\\.onCancelUploadButton').click()
```

which is working fine. This is will clear the fields.

Now I wish when I click on this `Cancel` button some other button should also be clicked so I'm doing this:

```
$('#whitelist\\.onCancelUploadButton').click(function() { $('#fileUploader').trigger('click') } )
```

After this statement when I do:

```
$('#whitelist\\.onCancelUploadButton').click()
```

its not triggering the click of the `fileUploader`. But the fields are cleared. But when when I try manually in browser the `fileUploader` click event is working.

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Would you mind preparing a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

valid ID in html should match:

```
[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*
```

1. Must Start with A-Z or a-z characters
2. May contains _(hyphen), :(colan) and .(dot)

but one should avoid `:` and `.` beacause:

For example, an ID could be labelled "a.b:c" and referenced in the style sheet as #a.b:c but as well as being the id for the element, it could mean id "a", class "b", pseudo-selector "c". Best to avoid the confusion and stay away from using . and : altogether.

so change it to:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="supportButton" id="whiteListOnCancelUploadButton" onclick="whitelistonCancelUpload();">
```

and then try:

```
$('#whiteListOnCancelUploadButton').click();
```